# tcp to http proxy via nginx

Tags: nginx, http, tcp

I have an nginx server that accepts tcp connection. I need that request to be forwarded to an upstream application server listening on http . Can someone please help me out with a snippet or some docs.

Comment: Please clarify, what is exactly the "TCP connection" nginx accepts? Where does that connection come from? What does the communication from client look like? What is your existing nginx configuration?

Answer (score -1):

This one enables many features ( manually search for how to upgrade your ssl preferences [Medium has a good example](https://medium.com/@aditya.vssut/setting-up-nginx-configuration-to-get-an-a-in-ssl-labs-server-test-e0e25098d634)

- upgrades to SSL
- enables http2 & keepalive
- lets you generate clients in frontend and backend to have it e.g. served in your local network with a real cert

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name frontend.com;
#    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    access_log            /var/log/nginx/frontend80.access.log main;
#    location /.well-known {  
#            alias /var/www/letsencrypt_webroot/.well-known;
#    }

        location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            }


       location /.well-known {

          proxy_set_header        Host $host;
          proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    #      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

          # Fix the It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
          proxy_pass          http://192.168.1.1:80;
          proxy_read_timeout  90;

            }

    }



    upstream destination.hq {
          keepalive 50;
        server 192.168.1.1:443   ;
        }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name frontend.com;
        client_max_body_size 4096M;

        ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/frontend.com/fullchain.pem;
        #/etc/ssl/private/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/frontend.com/privkey.pem;
        #/etc/ssl/private/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate   /etc/letsencrypt/live/frontend.com/fullchain.pem;

    #    ssl on;
        ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
        #ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        #ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

        access_log            /var/log/nginx/frontend.com.access.log main;
        location / {

         client_max_body_size 4096M;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header        Host $host;
          proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    #      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
          proxy_set_header Host            $upstream_addr;
          add_header       X-Host          $host;
          # Fix the It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
          proxy_pass          https://destination.hq;
          proxy_read_timeout  90;

          #proxy_redirect      https://backend.local:8443 https://frontend.com;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Is this example for http to http proxy or tcp to http proxy  ?

Comment: at first it looks that you not telling what you really want to do? second if only a port is needed try to use port forwarding via iptables

Comment: @ArunPolisetty this one uses https backend , you could change it by altering the port number in upstream to  `server 192.168.1.1:80 `  and the proy line to   `proxy_pass          http://`